# Oracle analytical function suggestions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have some metrics tracked on a project whose value keeps increasing as time goes by.

Sample data:

```
 Project | Date        | Metric%
---------------------------------
  P1     | 05-Jan-2015 |  40
  P1     | 10-Jan-2015 |  50
  P1     | 05-Feb-2015 |  60
  P1     | 01-Mar-2015 |  70
  P1     | 25-Mar-2015 |  80
  P1     | 03-Apr-2015 |  90
```

I need month wise effective value as below. If there a metric value on the 1st of the month, then it is used else the last measured value in the previous month is used.

```
 Project | Month Start Date | Effective Metric%
------------------------------------------------
   P1    | 01-Feb-2015      |   50
   P1    | 01-Mar-2015      |   70
   P1    | 01-Apr-2015      |   80
   P1    | 01-May-2015      |   90
```

I'm using a sql like below to get this:

```
select sq2.project_id, sq2.mon_start_dt, sq2.metric_value
from
(select
    sq1.project_id,
    trunc(sq1.metric_measurement_dt, 'MONTH') mon_start_dt, -- gives date in the format 01MMYYYY
    /* Check if metric_measurement_dt is 1st day of month (01MMYYYY), if so use the metric value else use previous metric value */
    case when extract(day FROM sq1.metric_measurement_dt) = 1 then sq1.metric_current_val else sq1.metric_previous_val end metric_value,
from
(
    /* Get current and previous metric values for all measurement dates */
    select
        project_id,
        metric_measurement_dt,
        row_number() over (partition by project_id, extract(month from metric_measurement_dt) order by metric_measurement_dt) mm_start_row,
        metric_value metric_current_val,
        lag(metric_value) over (partition by project_id order by     metric_measurement_dt) metric_previous_val,
        from  table t1 
    ) sq1
    where sq1.mm_start_row = 1) sq2
where sq2.metric_value is not null;
```

The above query does not give me the row for `01-May-2015`. I believe this is because there is no measurement that has happened in the month of May.

Can you give some comments on fixing this issue?

Comment: why does your project number increase in your output?

Comment: also, how does your output have may in it, when your data only goes up to april

Comment: Project number should not change in output. I have corrected this.

Comment: Since there is a measurement on 03-Apr-2015, this would be effective on 01-May-2015

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach.  For each record, get the current value and the previous value.  Also, enumerate the values within a month.  Then, choose the first value in the month.  If the day of the month is "1", take the current value.  Otherwise, take the previous value:

```
select project_id, trunc(metric_measurement_dt, 'MONTH') as mon,
       (case when extract(day from metric_measurement_dt) = 1 then metric_value
             else prev_value
        end) as metric_value
from (select project_id, metric_measurement_dt, metric_value,
             row_number() over (partition by project_id, extract(month from metric_measurement_dt)
                                order by metric_measurement_dt) as seqnum,
             lag(metric_value) over (partition by project_id
                                     order by metric_measurement_dt) as prev_value
      from table t1 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

`LAST_DAY(dt-1)+1` assigns the 1st of the next month to every date less than the first of month. And then you simply apply a `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT Project, Metric,
      LAST_DAY(dt-1)+1 AS dt,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY Project, LAST_DAY(dt-1)+1
            ORDER  BY dt DESC) AS rn
   FROM tab
 ) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Could the down voter please comment? This is returning exactly the requested result.